# QtSpim Exception occurred at PC=0x00000000

Tags: assembly, qtspim

So I have just started using QtSimp for my classes but I cannot simulate a single programm

e.g.

```
.data        # Data declaration section
 hello_msg:   .asciiz "Hello World!\n";

    .text

main:                # Start of code section

    la $a0, hello_msg
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    # Now do a graceful exit
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

I will load the file normally but when I try to run it, these errors occure:

```
Exception occurred at PC=0x00000000
Bad address in text read: 0x00000000
Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x80000180
```

This seems to be my case for any programm that I have tried so far

QtSpim version: 9.1.4

Comment: Unable to reproduce with QtSpim 9.1.12. Make sure that you're loading the right assembly file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. Your QtSpim isn't using the default address of 0x00400000. You can set it by going to **Simulator -> Run Parameters** and change the value of **Address or label to start running program** from 0x00000000 to 0x00400000.